# How can I use jquery events to pass variables to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with a drop-down to select a time for scheduling

[image]

I didn't use a selector input, instead I used the following html to make the menu for styling reasons.

```
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="apt-time">
    <h3>&#64;Time</h3>
    <ul class="time-list">
      <li class="available">8:00am</li>
      <li class="available">9:00am</li>
      <li class="available">10:00am</li>
      <li class="available">11:00am</li>
      <li class="available">12:00am</li>
      <li class="available">1:00pm</li>
      <li class="available">2:00pm</li>
      <li class="available">3:00pm</li>
      <li class="available">4:00pm</li>
      <li class="available">5:00pm</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because of this I can't use the POST method to get the data the user clicked on in the menu. So I tried to come up with a solution that could pass a string variable with events to my php page with the GET method in the code below. The if statements are going to be used so the client can't submit the form without clicking on an option in the menu. Is there a way around this without using a selector input?

```
$('.available').click(function() {
  return clockTime = $(event.target).text()
})
$('.btn').click(function() {
  if ($('.available').click) {
    window.location.href = "textsms.php?"+clockTime
  } else {
    // warn client that they need to chose a time
  }
})
```

Comment: I think you would need AJAX for this

Comment: `$('.available').click` - that does not look like a valid condition to be used in an `if` statement

Comment: It isn't a valid condition, it was used for testing, but I don't know a condition I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `AJAX` functionality below. The script passes `POST` values to PHP script named `textsms.php` without refreshing browser.

**Updated Code:**

```
<script>
$('.available').click(function() {
        var clockTime = $(this).text();
        $.ajax({
             url:"textsms.php",
             method:"POST",
             data:{'clockTime':clockTime,var2:'2',}, // modify fields
             success: function(data){
                alert(data); // Do something with data received
            },
       });    

});</script>
```

For testing..

**textsms.php:**

```
<?php
print_r( $_POST );
?>
```

Comment: Would I then use $_POST['clockTime']; in my php script? Also not really sure what the 'success' method is for, but I'll research it. The alert(data) is working so this is getting me in the right direction I think.

Comment: Yes you can use that variable in your php script. If you need more, in js script, you can just add it in the line containing the clockTime and var2 variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining the get variable in the redirection:

```
window.location.href = "textsms.php?"+clockTime
```

The following will store the "clockTime" in the $_GET['time']

```
window.location.href = "textsms.php?time="+clockTime
```

Edit: Anyway your JS is not correct.

```
var clockTime;
$('.available').click(function(e) {
    clockTime = $(this).text();
})
$('.btn').click(function() {
    if(typeof clockTime !== "undefined"){
        window.location.href = "textsms.php?time="+clockTime
    }else{
        // warn client that they need to chose a time
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a control variable for this (also defining a css class that show the selected option):

```
var selectedTime = '';

$('.available').click(function() {
   $('.available').removeClass('clicked');
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
   selectedTime = $(this).text();
})

$('.btn').click(function() {
  if (selectedTime != '') {
      window.location.href = "textsms.php?time="+selectedTime;
  } else {
    // warn client that they need to chose a time
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value and pass it to your location properly:

```
$("ul.time-list").on("click","li.available",function(){
  var selectedTime = $(this).text();
  window.location.href = "textsms.php?varname="+selectedTime;
});
```

I like using jquery's on event as it allows you to use load content dynamically so long as you target an external static element.

http://api.jquery.com/on/